# zlib inflation corrupts when using small buffers

Tags: c++, c, zlib

I need to inflate big strings with zlib (around 500 KiB) and i noticed that when using a small buffer the output is corrupted (random letters get converted into giberish) but when switching to a large buffer the output is not corrupted.

This is my code:

```cpp
                std::string str;
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);

                stream_.next_in = (unsigned char*)deflated.data();
                stream_.avail_in = deflated.size();

                int result = Z_OK;

                do
                {
                    char buffer[1024] = { 0 };

                    stream_.next_out = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(buffer);
                    stream_.avail_out = sizeof(buffer);

                    result = ::inflate(&stream_, Z_NO_FLUSH);

                    str.append(buffer);
                } while (result == Z_OK);

                inflated = std::move(str);
```

Now at 1024 the output gets corrupted but if i switch it to 256 KiB (char buffer[263168]) the output is fine. How can I solve this problem without having to switch to such a big buffer?

Comment: I'd probably add a check to see that the result was successful before you try to append it to the str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `inflate()` writes all 1024 bytes to the `char` array, then the `char` array won't have any NUL-terminator byte, so when you do your `str.append(buffer)`, what gets added to your `inflated` string will be the 1024 chars in the array, plus whatever garbage bytes happen to be on the stack after the array, until the first NUL byte is encountered.

I suggest setting `stream._avail_out = sizeof(buffer)-1;` to avoid that problem.

Comment: Ah man that's a rookie mistake :) Either way thank you, it works.